# Binomial distribution with mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

Can anyone help me with homework? I can`t catch a basic idea of the next exercise:
$$
X\thicksim Bin(20,0.2)\\P(|X-\mu|\le\sigma)=?
$$
Can anyone at least explain how it opens,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We have for a Binomial distribution;
$$E(X)=\mu=n \cdot p$$
$$Var(X)=\sigma^2=n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)$$

Comment: Thanx, but I know already that. I just don`t know what to do with this information

Comment: Well we then have to calculate $P(|X - 4| \le \sqrt{3.2}) = P((4-\sqrt{3.2}) \le X \le (4+\sqrt{3.2}))$

Comment: That is what I just tried to do using PDF function, but I get quite strange results of that.

Comment: As the binomial distribution is discrete we should only be finding $P(3 \le X \le 5)$ but this is equivalent to what I gave above. i.e $0.59812...$

Comment: Thanx, your explanation was helpful